# Live streaming delphi firemonkey android

Tags: android, delphi, html5-video, firemonkey, live-streaming

How to play a live stream (rtmp, HLS) to an android device using delphi firemonkey? I tried google but only found how to play a video file.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this  ExoPlayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer